# How to remove item from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, object

How can I remove an item from a JavaScript object?

Like this:

```
var test = {'red':'#FF0000', 'blue':'#0000FF'};
test.remove('blue');
```

Comment: I believe this is the solution [How to remove a property from a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: delete test['blue'];

Answer (score 798):

```js
var test = {'red':'#FF0000', 'blue':'#0000FF'};
delete test.blue; // or use => delete test['blue'];
console.log(test);
```

this deletes test.blue

Comment: This works great, you can check it here live: http://jsfiddle.net/b8whD/2/

Comment: What if we've an object like that : `{0: 'red', 1:'green', 2:'blue'}` `delete test.0` will fail.

Comment: @Hotgeart but `delete test[0]` will succeed. Although, if you are using naturally incrementing integers for your object keys maybe consider an array?

Comment: Does `delete` added in ES6?

Comment: @Kermani No, `delete` has existed since ES1. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Specifications

Comment: @PatrickFinnigan It is funny, because I did not expect to see any easy good from ES1 :)

Comment: How is it performance wise? Has anyone done testing around it?

Comment: delete does not works at node 8.11.*, what is the solution?

Comment: @151291 I can confirm that the above works for node 8.11.3 and 10.9.0. I am unsure of your problem. However, If you wish for a more *modern* solution you could try

`Object.keys(test).reduce((a,b) => b === 'blue' ? ({...a}) : ({...a, [b]: test[b]}),{})` 

But note that this will note mutate test, but rather create a new Object whose only entry would be `{red: '#FF0000'}`

Comment: delete isn't working for me in mongoose, however, I can just set an object to an empty object (if I wanted to delete/hide the whole thing) and it does the trick.

Comment: Destructuring an object would be a prominent solution considering ES6 @MohammadKermani