# Remove object so it doesn't iterate in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a basic setup for my data like this:

```
myObj = {};
myObj[3] = {};
myObj[3].stuff = 'hello';
myObj[4] = {};
myObj[4].stuff = 'hello';
```

Now at some point i want to remove [4] from myObj. Currently i set it to false but this still exists in myObj. Like this `Object {4: false}`.

The issue here is if i want to loop `myObj` it will still loop the 4 which i don't want it to do.

How can I setup my data correctly so I can remove a given object and thus won't be iterated in a for loop.

Example of my loop is:

```
var i = 0;
for(var j in myObj){
  i++;
}
console.log(i); // = 2
```

Is there no way to rid of [4] so the total is then only 1?

Comment: and this one too:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295087/remove-item-from-object

Comment: @alfasin this ain't about arrays but sudhir is correct my bad :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delete operator:

```
delete myObj[4];
```

Comment: Yeh i will. Theres 3 minute wait till i can tick it :)